# I'm having so much fun watching

Tags: grammar, construction

I'm trying to analyze the construction of this sentence:

> I'm having so much fun watching.

1. *so much fun* = NP, Direct Object of the verb *am having*
2. *watching* =

My question is, is #2 an NP (and gerund) functioning as an object complement of #1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, "watching" is just called a V+ing Clause (so you could probably call it a Gerund Clause too).

But neither a Noun Phrase nor an Object Complement.

One of the most common uses of the V+ing Clauses is to talk about 2 things happening at the same time:

Ex. She went home crying.

Don't just stand there doing nothing.

Comment: After giving it a thought, I was led to the idea that this type of construction is a result of **deletion**: _She went home while she was crying_ is the full sentence which is reduced to _She went home while crying_ which is further reduced to _She went home crying._ Do you think this is wrong?

Comment: You mean omission or abbreviation? Yes, you got it

Comment: Yes -- omission. (Since no further answers have been proposed here, I'll now accept yours.)